# Connect Xiomi android Tv box through ADB

Tags: android-tv

I am using Xiomi android TV box for developing android TV application. For debugging when we connect through ADB using its IP address it gives following error

```
unable to connect to 10.1.1.84:5555: cannot connect to 10.1.1.84:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

Where as it is debugging through USB cable very well.

How can we connect through ADB with its IP address using command prompt?

Comment: You have to switch adb mode to tcpip first: adb tcpip <PORT>. But you need device to be wired connected first. To connect MiBox from Xiomi you will need adapter like (usb-A-female to micro-usb-male)

Comment: Sorry, it should be usb-A-male to micro-usb-female, so you can use standard micro-usb cable to connect box to your development machine

Comment: With MIBOX3 and Android version 8.0.0 you can connect over wifi without any problems. Which version of the box and software did you use?

Answer (score -1):

by default wireless or network debug on in MIBOX
try connect using adb connect 192.12.1.15